# Is Powershell Get-ADGroup recursive?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

If I am running the following command:

```
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $SearchBase -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "group"'
```

will that return nested groups? If not, what is the best way to return nested groups?

I have tried running the following but get an error:

```
 $ADGroups = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $SearchBase

Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'OU=ABC,DC=COMPANY,DC=net' under: 'DC=COMPANY,DC=ne
t'.
At line:1 char:30
+ $ADGroups = Get-ADGroupMember <<<<  -Identity $SearchBase
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound:
```

Answer (score 2):

As [`Get-ADGroups`'s help page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617196.aspx), states the default value for the `-SearchScope` parameter - which you're not using - is `Subtree`.

In other words: yes, `Get-ADGroup` *is* recursive by default.

The other permissible values are `Base` (search only the object at the specified path itself) and `OneLevel` (search the object itself as well as its immediate *children*).

---

Using explicit `-Filter` value `'ObjectClass -eq "group"'` with `Get-ADGroup` is pointless, because any objects returned will *by definition* be *groups*.
In order to find *all* groups in the specified search scope, simply use `-Filter *`:

```
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase
```

---

To actually get groups' *members* recursively, you can use `Get-ADUser` *directly* with the `-SearchBase` property:

```
$members = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase
```

---

Note that the `-Identity` parameter can only be used to target *one* specific item, using something that uniquely identifies it, namely "its distinguished name (DN), GUID, security identifier (SID), Security Accounts Manager (SAM) account name, or canonical name.".